# John the ripper multiple mask attack

Tags: password-cracking, john-the-ripper

I am going to use John the Ripper on a multi-core server to crack about 400 Windows NT hashes. Depending on my CPU capacities I want to check all passwords that satisfy following masks:

```
?1?1?1?1?1?1?1 --min-len=1

?2?2?2?2?2?2?2?2 --min-len=8

?3?3?3?3?3?3?3?3?3 --min-len=9

?4?4?4?4?4?4?4?4?4?4 --min-len=10
```

where:

```
-1: ?l?u?d?s

-2: ?l?u?d

-3: ?l?d

-4: ?l
```

I have 16 cores (32 threads) so I am planning to run using `--fork=16 or --fork=32`. The only part I have not find is how to run more masks in one command.

PS: I have to use JtR, not HashCat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to pass a list of [masks](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/doc/MASK) to john as a single command (in the way that hashcat allows).

The best you can do today is to use the custom placeholder syntax (-1, -2, etc.) just as you've done, and run each command separately (which could be combined into a single run with a batch or command file).

(And if your limitation on hashcat is just that you can't use OpenCL, this attack is simple enough that you could use [hashcat-legacy](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat-legacy/releases) (download [here](https://hashcat.net/files_legacy/hashcat-2.00.7z)), which is CPU-only.)